# How can I launch a new tab and then continue with my script execution?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, pageobjects, page-object-gem

While executing a scenario, I need to **launch a new tab** within a browser and execute my script. Can we able to achieve it using Cucumber Page Object.

Also I need to interact with old and new tab intermittently. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your test launches the new tab as part of its actions then this answer should help you to switch to the new tab - [Controlling new tab to operate using Watir? (Ruby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457690/controlling-new-tab-to-operate-using-watir-ruby)

If you want to open a new browser instance to complete some other part of the test then you can just create a second browser with watir. e.g.

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
@second_browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

and then pass in the relevant browser instance to your page object constructor

```
my_page_object = MyPageObjectClass.new(@second_browser)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

`page.driver.browser.switch_to.window (page.driver.browser.window_handles.last)`

switch_to is a selenium method that allows you to change context to a new window. window_handles is a list of currently open windows.

More details in [Selenium docs](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) in the section "Moving Between Windows and Frames".  The docs are for javascript, but there are also [Ruby Bindings](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings).